# php mysql database connection issue

Tags: php, mysql

When i upload db.php page to the server it's say

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user     
'somename'@'somenumber' (using password: YES) in /home/somename/public_html/db/db.php on 
line 2 Could not connect to Server: Access denied for user 'somename'@'somenumber' 
(using password: YES)
```

Why it's say ?

db.php code:

```
<?php   
$db = mysql_connect('www.mysite.com', 'somename', 'password'); 
if (!$db)         
{
die('Could not connect to Server: ' . mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_select_db("datbasename",$db))
{
die('Could not connect to DataBase : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Because access is denied for that user.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'd like to give +10 for that comment :)

Comment: @@OliCharlesworth, so there is no user with that name ?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth But i can access cpanel with that username and password.

Comment: I don't know PHP much, but can you see how here connection is made...

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8951736/1066828

Answer (score 1):

In mysql it' not only username and password, but also host that matters while connecting.

Your username and password may work for `localhost` but to connect from `host1.someserver.com` you will need different credentials.

In your case `@'somenumber'` may be IP address that you are connecting from, ensure that username you are using is allowed to connect from this IP.

Comment: well, @dev-null-dweller, But i can access with that username and password. so that i use in db.php code: Host= www.mysite.com, Username= myusername and password= password. But Error..!!

Comment: You can acces your database from one host, but as i said this credentials may not work when connecting from other hosts. Instead of blindly trying to connect, contact your hosting provider to get more help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access to the database because your usename + password aren't correct.

Comment: But i can access cpanel with that username and password.

Answer (score 0):

`line 2 Could not connect to Server: Access denied for user 'somename'@'somenumber'` says CLEARLY, access is denied for the user `somename`. Get privileges to get connected first...

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Either the password is wrong or you don't have enough privileges for the user.

Try with username as "root" and password as "" and see if it works, otherwise you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Well, @sh4nx0r i'm trying this.

Comment: it's say access denied for user 'root'

Answer (score 0):

In mysql_connect('www.mysite.com', 'somename', 'password');

you will need to give your database hostname, not your site hostname.

Check with your hosting provider for database hostname.

It is localhost if database is on same server/machine.